# gnome shell how to access eye of gnome application menu

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

So I'm a new archlinux user coming from ubuntu (unity version).
In Ubuntu, gnome application where looking like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904415/gnome-make-toolbars-appear-at-top-of-screen) where file, edit, view etc... where available.

In the Gnome photo application it was possible via this menu to do `Edit -> flip horizontal`. But now in gnome shell this menu is not available so I can't find `Edit`.
So where is it now ?

I have the same issue with the calendar app, I want to change the default first day of the week but I can't find where it is.

Currently I have only this available for the gnome photo application:

[image: Currently I have only this available]

Comment: Please ask a separate question for the calendar app.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the *gnome photos* menu it's the *image viewer* (aka `eog`) menu. You're right, the `Edit` entry is no longer present in that menu. You'll have to go into full screen mode via <kbd>F11</kbd> and move your mouse pointer to the top of the screen to access the new menu:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. But if the `Edit` entry is no longer here, where is it ? In your capture, you show the rotate button, I'm searching for the flip horizontal one.

Comment: @BoumTAC - there is no Edit and the flips are gone - no idea why (I suspect because an image viewer is not an editor...) You can only rotate.